# Trying to learn Convolution Neural Network with CIFAR-10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I want to implement a simple CNN with the following architecture:

1. conv1: convolution and rectied linear activation (RELU)
2. pool1: max pooling
3. FC2: fully connected layer with rectied linear activation (RELU)
4. softmax layer: nal output predictions i.e. classify into one of the ten 
   classes.

I am following this guide: https://towardsdatascience.com/cifar-10-image-classification-in-tensorflow-5b501f7dc77c but the CNN here is very complicated. Could someone please guide me on how to shorten this implementation or the code? I am also confused by the dimensions of the conv2d, weights, and bias.

Below is the code i am starting out with!

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

dir = 'C:/PythonProjects/cifar-10-batches-py/'

def unpickle(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
        dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
    return dict

def to_onehot(labels, nclasses):
    outlabels = np.zeros((len(labels),nclasses))
    for i,l in enumerate(labels):
        outlabels[i,l]=1
    return outlabels

def normalize(x):
    """
        argument
            - x: input image data in numpy array [32, 32, 3]
        return
            - normalized x 
    """
    min_val = np.min(x)
    max_val = np.max(x)
    x = (x-min_val) / (max_val-min_val)
    return x


data_dash = unpickle(dir+'data_batch_1')
data_test = unpickle(dir+'test_batch')

X = data_dash[b'data'] # m * n
X_test = data_test[b'data'] # m * n

train_X = X.reshape(-1, 32, 32, 3)
train_y = np.array(data_dash[b'labels'])
train_y = to_onehot(train_y,10)

test_X = X_test.reshape(-1,32,32,3)
test_y = np.array(data_test[b'labels'])
test_y = to_onehot(test_y,10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to start with the Keras API. Please refer this Cifar10 tutorial.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn.py

If you're using recent versions of tensorflow, then Keras API is available within tensorflow as tf.keras. Keras package need not be installed separately.

> I am also confused by the dimensions of the conv2d, weights, and bias.

From the source code here,
https://github.com/deep-diver/CIFAR10-img-classification-tensorflow/blob/c96a0cbbe91ee280a5de1b3b872e407b0a2c7f34/CIFAR10_image_classification.py#L139

The method `conv_net()` builds the network. There are 4 conv layers, taking the first conv layer,

```
conv1_filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=[3, 3, 3, 64], mean=0, stddev=0.08))
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv1_filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

The weights for the conv1 layer are saved in conv1_filter which has the format [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels].

[3, 3, 3, 64] is 3 x 3 filter with 3 input channels(RGB input as this is the first layer) and 64 output channels.

For conv2 layer, the input channels will be 64 which is the number of output  channels of conv1 layer and so on.

The weights stored in conv1_filter are updated during the training process by gradient descent.

There is no bias used here. If bias is required, then another tf.Variable needs to be declared with the size equal to the number of output channels. Then `tf.nn.bias_add()` method needs to be invoked to add the bias to the output of the conv layer.

Comment: But I am not supposed to use Keras, I want to use tensorflow

Comment: Updated the answer with clarifications about weights and biases. The method which builds the network is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation. But I was hoping you could help to modify my code so I can start of with the weights and bias for the CNN architecture?